# CSV Parsing for Book

Tags: python, django, algorithm, csv

I'm having trouble with a project in which I am parsing a csv file which will contain the sections and subsections of a textbook, and looks something like this:

```
Chapter, Section, Lesson  #this line shows how the book will be organized
Ch1Name, Secion1Name, Lesson1Name
Ch1Name, Secion2Name, Lesson1Name
Ch1Name, Secion2Name, Lesson2Name
```

I'm creating Django model objects for each section, and each section has a parent attribute which is the parent section it resides in.  I'm having trouble coming up with a way to go through the csv file in such a way that the parent assignments are correct.  Any ideas with how to get started would be great.

Comment: Hopefully the data in your CSV doesn't have spaces in it, or that'd make things interesting.  Anyway, [take a look at the csv module in Python.](http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, hopefully you're already using the `csv` module rather than trying to parse it manually.

Second, it's not entirely clear from your question, but it sounds like you're trying to build up a simple tree structure from the data as you read it.

So, something like this?

```
with open('book.csv') as book:
    chapters = collections.defaultdict(collections.defaultdict(list))
    book.readline() # to skip the headers
    for chapter_name, section_name, lesson_name in csv.reader(book):
        chapters[chapter_name][section_name].append(lesson_name)
```

Of course that's assuming you want an "associative tree"—a `dict` of `dict`s. A more normal linear tree, like a `list` of `list`s, or an implicit tree in the form of "parent pointers", is even simpler.

For example, let's say you have classes defined like this:

```
class Chapter(object):
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

class Section(object):
    def __init__(self, chapter, name):
        self.chapter = chapter
        self.name = name

class Lesson(object):
    def __init__(self, section, name):
        self.section = section
        self.name = name
```

And you want a `dict` for each, mapping names to objects. So:

```
with open('book.csv') as book:
    chapters, sections, lessons = {}, {}, {}
    book.readline() # to skip the headers
    for chapter_name, section_name, lesson_name in csv.reader(book):
        chapter = chapters.setdefault(chapter_name, Chapter(chapter_name))
        section = sections.setdefault(section_name, Section(chapter, section_name))
        lesson = lessons.setdefault(lesson_name, Lesson(section, lesson_name))
```

Now, you can pick a random lesson, and print its chapter and section:

```
lesson = random.choice(lessons.values())
print('Chapter {}, Section {}: Lesson {}'.format(lesson.section.chapter.name,
                                                 lesson.section.name, lesson.name))
```

---

One last thing to keep in mind: In this example, the parent references don't cause any circular references, because the parents don't have references to their children. But what if you need that?

```
class Chapter(object):
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        self.sections = {}

class Section(object):
    def __init__(self, chapter, name):
        self.chapter = chapter
        self.name = name
        self.lessons = {}

# ...

chapter = chapters.setdefault(chapter_name, Chapter(chapter_name))
section = sections.setdefault(section_name, Section(chapter, section_name))
chapters[section_name] = section
```

So far, so good… but what happens when you're done with all those objects? They have circular references, which can cause problems for garbage collection. Not insurmountable problems, but it does mean that objects won't get collected as quickly in most implementations. For example, in CPython, things normally get collected as soon as the last reference goes out of scope—but if you have circular references, that never happens, so nothing gets collected until the next pass of the cycle detector. The solution to this is to use a [`weakref`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/weakref.html) for the parent pointer (or a collection of `weakref`s to the children).

Comment: Thanks.  I actually am using the csv module, but thanks for the suggestion.  I think you're getting close to what I'm thinking of, but here's the problem: for example, from the csv example above, I need Section1 and Secion2 in Chapter1 to both point to the same Chapter1 section object.  I hope this makes sense.

Comment: OK, you want to build some kind of `Section` object? Let me edit the answer.

Comment: Thanks!  I think this will help me get unstuck!

Comment: Lesson needs a ForeignKey to a Section object, and Section needs a ForeignKey to a Chapter object. As you read each line in you see if there's already a section with that name and if not, create it, then create the Lesson object with that Session in the ForeignKey. To create a Session object, do the same with consideration for the Chapter on that line.

Comment: @Spacedman: I'm not sure what you mean by `ForeignKey`. If you look at my example, `Lesson` _has_ a reference to its `Section`. If you're saying that reference should be called `ForeignKey` instead of `section` (or `parent`), I disagree. If you're not saying that, I don't know what you _are_ saying.

Comment: This is a Django model? A ForeignKey: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/

Comment: @Spacedman: Ah, I see what you mean. If you want to read the data from the .csv file, then write it to a database that backs the django model, then yes.